# Is there a war file of James-3 to deploy it in glassfish / tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, glassfish, mail-server, james

I am using James-3-beta-4 mail server from apache, where can i find the server as a war file to deploy it in the application server? Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to get the source (have a look [here](http://james.apache.org/server/3/dev-build.html)) to build it by yourself.

Use `mvn package` to create a WAR file.